# Selecting contours which heights are integers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute, contour

I have a Contours Featureclass, with an interval of 0.2 meters. I wish to select only those Contours, which are at 1 m interval?

I have tried using the following syntax in the 'Select by Attribute' dialog (in ArcMap), but it selects all the contours:

```
Mod("ELEVATION", 1)=0
```

What query should I run?

Comment: Saved a LOT of time for me, really thanks! Never seen this query codes like "Flor", "Elevation" and "Mod".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The simple trick to select only Integer values, is to use the following syntax:

`Mod(Round("ELEVATION", 0)*10, 10)=0`

This Multiplication by 10, makes all the values Integer, and then we select only those which are multiples of 10.

In case you wish to select Multiples of some other number, just multiply 10 by the interval.

- To get contours at 5 m intervals, use:

  `Mod(Round("ELEVATION",0) * 10, 50)=0`
- To get contours at 100 m interval use:

  `Mod(Round("ELEVATION", 0) * 10, 1000)=0`

**Update**
As per Whuber's advice given in the comment below, I have added the rounding function in the query expression.

Comment: I don't think I would trust these solutions. The problem is that with non-integral intervals of 0.2, the database is likely storing them as floats. Consequently `MOD` will be subject to floating-point roundoff error--and that's critical here: if you're low by even the very least significant digit, `MOD` may return the wrong value (depending on how it is implemented). I would like to suggest *rounding* the values before applying `MOD` as a way of preventing these subtle (and insidious) errors.

Comment: You need to round after multiplying by 10, but before finding the mod.

Comment: If I want to select contours at 5m intervals, the formula implemented as-written above selects non-integers that round to a number that is evenly divisible by 5. *E.g.*, 14.5m and 19.5m were selected but this is not desired. These were not selected if I dropped the 'Round' part of the function.

Comment: @delongtime If you have contours that are supposed to have non-integral levels, simply modify the second argument of `ROUND` to achieve more precision in the rounding.

Comment: I am not sure the update of this was done correctly.  Shouldn't the Round be done on the "ELEVATION" * 10 not the "ELEVATION".   Maybe like this: Mod(Round( "ELEVATION" *10 , 0), 10)=0

Answer (score 9):

Here is another query option. It largely does the same as the answers listed above but is (in my opinion) a little bit easier to customise for different scenarios.

To display any contour divisible by 10

```
Floor(Elevation/10)=Elevation/10
```

To display any contour divisible by 50

```
Floor(Elevation/50)=Elevation/50
```

To display half metre contours

```
Floor(Elevation/0.5)=Elevation/0.5
```

To display 10 metre contours with an arbitary offset (eg 10.2, 20.2, 30.2)

```
Floor((Elevation-0.2)/10)=(Elevation-0.2)/10
```

At the end of the day, this is just another option to consider.

Answer (score 2):

This was meant to be a comment on the above answer - *sorry*.

Syntax would vary depending on the type of DB your Contours are stored in but the given solution seems to pick contours after rounding their values. So for example in my test this achieved a selected set that included .3 m as well as .4 m. In fact, it excluded none of the values.

This equation

`Mod(Round("ELEVATION" * 10, 0), 2)=0`

Gave me results that seemed to match what the questioner was asking.

Answer (score 1):

To get Index contours I use this on Field Calculator:

**In ARCMAP**

```
dim dIndexInterval
dim dCont
dim i
dim j
dim k
dim c

dIndexInterval = 200 ' set to interval of index contours
dCont = [level] ' Set to contour height field

i = ROUND(dCont, 0) * 10
j = dIndexInterval * 10
k = i MOD j

if k = 0 then
 c = 1 ' is an index contour
else
 c = 0 ' is not an index contour
end if
```

'Type "c" (without quotes) in the text input field at the bottom of the dialog box and click OK.

**In QGIS**

```
if(((round("level", 0) * 10) % (200 * 10)) = 0, 1, 0)
```

""level"" Set to contour height field
"200"  Set to interval of index contours

Then:
"1" is an index contour and "0" is not an index contour

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the contour by 10 and then modulus by 10 to determine if there's a remainder.  If there's no remainder than it's an integer, else it's float.

```
def contour_class(contour):
    if ((contour * 10) % 10) == 0:
        return "Integer"
    else:
        return "Float"

__esri_field_calculator_splitter__
contour_class(!Contour!)
```