# Help with definition query

Tags: cartography, contour, definition-query

I have a layer of 5ft contour lines, and it includes a field called "Elevation" that has the elevation of that particular line in feet, (ex: 1555, 1560, 1565 etc.). I want to only show lines for every 10ft of elevation though. Is there a definition query I can put on the Elevation field to give me only lines for every 10 feet of elevation?

Comment: You can use a modulus function, but we can't really help until you specify the data source type, the datatype of the "Elevation" field, and the GIS software involved (with version)

Comment: the answer will be some variation of: mod(elevation, 10) = 0 but as @Vince says without more details we can't give you exact syntax

Comment: also have a look at this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58224/how-do-i-select-only-those-contours-who-heights-are-integers

Comment: If you're going to make extensive edits, please don't forget to incorporate changes that have been requested to make the question answerable.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple. If your values are in 5 foot intervals and your elevation field is a numeric field, you can use a modulus query in the Definition Query to only show those records whose elevation value is even or odd.

In your case, you're looking for even numbers.

For a Personal Geodatabase, you'd use:

```
[Elevation]/2 MOD 2
```

For Shapefiles or File Geodatabases, use:

```
MOD ("Elevation",  2)  = 0
```

Conversely, to select odd values you'd want to do the following:
For a Personal Geodatabases, use:

```
[Elevation] MOD 2
```

For Shapefiles or File Geodatabases, use:

```
MOD ("Elevation",  2)  = 1
```

Comment: +1 although `[Elevation]/2 MOD 2` doesn't work for me in a Personal GDB - I have to use `([Elevation] + 1) MOD 2`.